# How to get exact result from charindex?

Tags: sql, t-sql, charindex

```
select * 
from table_name 
where charindex(dest_mail,'abc@mail.com') >0
```

In the above query dest_mail is a column, but there is another entry in the table, which is `'bc@mail.com'`. When I try to execute the above query, I'm getting two results

```
1.abc@mail.com
2.bc@mail.com
```

How to get exact `'abc@mail.com'`?

Comment: When you execute: `select * from table_name where charindex(dest_mail,'abc@mail.com') >0` you **don't** get `'bc@mail.com'` in the results, right? Why don't you clarify what you do exactly.

Comment: `dest_mail` is a table??

Comment: when i try to execute the above, i get two results, which are 'abc@mail.com' and 'bc@mail.com'.

Comment: No, dest_mail is a column.

Comment: So now edit your question and provide correct info, with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Because this: *In the above query dest_mail is a table, but there is another entry in the table* does not make sense.

Comment: why not use `... WHERE dest_mail = 'abc@mail.com'`?

Comment: Your use of `CharIndex` is: if the email address can be found in "abc@mail.com" then return the row. Both "abc@mail.com" and "bc@mail.com" can be found in "abc@mail.com", so why are the results a surprise?

Comment: Yes, But is there any way to get exact match of 'abc@mail.com' using charindex.

Comment: If `CharIndex` returns `1` and the `DataLength` values match then it's an exact match. (You don't want "abc@mail.com" to match "abc@mail.com.au", hence the length check.) It still seems easier and clearer to use `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `=`?

```
where dest_mail = 'abc@mail.com'
```

Also, `charindex()` is not very colloquial SQL for this purpose; `=` is a built-in standard operator (`charindex()` is not standard).  And a bonus to `=` is that it allows the optimizer to take advantage of indexes and partitions.

Comment: That query can contain multiple mail id's. 
Example : select * from table_name where charindex(dest_mail,'abc@mail.com,b@mail.com') >0

Comment: @Bhargav . .  Then you would use `in`.